# Sling Models OSGI Configuration

Tags: maven, osgi, aem, sling

I'd like to setup Sling Models in our sling based project (actually it is an AEM project). I followed the instructions at http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html but unfortunately the adapTo method on a resource returns null, so I think I made some mistake in my OSGI configuration setup. Unfortunately I don't get any log file error, so now I need some help :)
We work with the maven-bundle-plugin which I configured the following way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
            <instructions>
                    <!-- we have to export for the classes to be visible -->
                    <Export-Package>
                            com.company.project.*;version=${project.version}
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>
                            org.apache.felix.scr;version="[1.6,2)",
                            org.apache.sling.api;version="[2.1,3)",
                            org.apache.sling.api.request;version="[2.1,3)",
                            org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler;version="[2.1,3)",
                            *                                                        
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Private-Package>
                            org.apache.sling.models.*
                    </Private-Package>
                    <Include-Resource>
                            {maven-resources}
                    </Include-Resource>
                    <Sling-Model-Packages>
                            com.company.project.models.componentgroup
                    </Sling-Model-Packages>
            </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The Model is implemented as an interface:

```
package com.company.project.models.componentgroup;

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Default;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;

import javax.inject.Inject;


@Model(adaptables = Resource.class)
public interface MyModel {

    @Inject
    @Default(values = "My Property Value")
    String getMyProperty();

}
```

I got a Controller class in which a SlingResource adapts to the Model, but returns null:

```
MyModel model = resource.adaptTo(MyModel.class);
```

I'm really thankful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it work by installing the bundels org.apache.sling.models.api and org.apache.sling.models.impl manually with the install function in the OSGI Felix console and removing

```
<Private-Package>
    org.apache.sling.models.*
</Private-Package>
```

It works with interfaces and classes, like expected :)

So my error is in the maven-bundle-plugin configuration, because the bundles aren't visible with Private-Package.

Where do you suggest to add the sling.models in the maven-bundle-plugin configuration?

Comment: This solved it for me!, you can also drop those two files in the install folder in the content module so you don't have to add it using the web console.

Comment: I was doing the same thing and finding the same error now it is solved for me but i don't know  what you are doing incorrect ....i have created a git repo for it .Take the reference https://github.com/gargshivani111/slingmodels.git
I hope it will help you.

Comment: To answer your question, you don't include sling.models package in maven-bundle-plugin. It's already available `provided` by default as a bundle in AEM.

For more information about the bundle-plugin and specifically `private-package` see this: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#private-package

Also, you'r answer is correct, please accept it.